# onMapReady gets called twice on first run

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView inside an own fragment (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.fragments.MapsFragment">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map_view" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I have the problem, that only on the first run when I run the app on my device the callback onMapReady gets called twice. When I stop the app and run it again, this does not happen again. Code:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

   [...]

    return v;
}
```

Additionally I call these callbacks of the map view: onResume, onPause, onDestroy, onLowMemory. I do not use the mMapView variable anywhere else.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong in my MapView implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are not initializing fragment twice?

Comment: Okay, indeed that is the problem, and it only happens on the first run. This means it has something to do with the rest of my implementation. Thanks!

Comment: So, how did you solve your problem @mapf ??

Comment: Unfortunately this is more than 2 years ago and I do not know anymore. I think it had something to do how I implemented the fragment. I also checked the commit history from back then and could not find anything special about it. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

If you are using it like a `View` it will be called automatically.